How do I update my Facebook Business token from my Python application?
I have a Python application that uses a Facebook Business library. Therefore, I need to use a token provided by Facebook to access my insights and manipulate them.
However, this token has an expiration date, which is long, but I wanted to know if there is a way to update this token automatically within my application, so that it doesn't stop running.
